# How To Hide My Google+ Profile?

Tags: google-plus

if I want to hide my Google+ profile from everyone i.e make it from public to private, how can this be done? I have different strangers adding me into their circles which I don't like.

Comment: Have you seen [this help page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1047279)?

Comment: I think you may be missing the point of G+. If someone Circles you, but you don't Circle them, the only things they can see are the things you make/post to "Public". (Except your name and profile photo. Those things can't be private.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make your Google+ profile completely private. You can hide most of the information, but you cannot hide your name or profile photo.

If you really want to keep people from adding you to their Circles, you'll need to Block them.